# numpy roll along a single axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with binary values that I need to change in the following way: The value of every element must be shifted one column to the left but only within the same row. As an example, I have the following array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1]])
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

And it needs to be transformed to:

```
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I know that `np.roll(arr,-1)` would roll the values one cell to the left, but it doesn't seem to be able to roll them within the rows they belong to (i.e. the element on cell [1,0] goes to [0,3] instead of the desired [1,3]. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

`roll` accepts an axis parameter:

```
np.roll(arr,-1, axis=1)

array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```